# QuickGraph : Cycle Detection

Tags: c#, graph, quickgraph

I am currelty working on a application where i need to detect a cycle from a undirectedgraph.I got a implementation in c# for the same but it is very slow.I found Quickgraph Sdk but not able to find any implementation or sample or documentation for the same.

If anyone knows about the implemetation or walkthorughs of quickgraph then please let me know as it very urgent for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know quickgraph, but finding cycles in an undirected graph should be doable in O(n) by searching depth first and marking each visited node... if you explore a new edge to an already visited node you have a cycle in your graph.

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply but i am looking for quickgraph implementation of cycle detection.Quickgraph is similar implemetation of graph library known as Boost which is in C.